# Variable declaration - Twitter API Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth

I'm using [Twitter API](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) for my project. When a user log in using Twitter I set up the configuration as the documentation says.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_twitter_client

  private
    def set_twitter_client
      if user_signed_in?
        @twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
          config.consumer_key        = "xxx"
          config.consumer_secret     = "xxx"
          config.access_token        = current_user.token
          config.access_token_secret = current_user.token_secret
        end
      end
    end
end
```

However, everytime a user load a page, this declaration is recall and I end up with a quota overflow, that's annoying. I tried to declare this variable only once and store it in a session variable but it doesn't work.

So my question is, what is the best way to declare this configuration variable ? Is it possible to declare it once for every user connected and store it somewhere ? Or do I need to recall it every time a user load a new page ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an initializer for your configuration. Anything in config/initializers will run once when rails starts up and this provides a central location to configure / wire up things. For example in config/initializers/twitter_initializer.rb :

```
TwitterClient = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
      config.access_token        = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
      config.access_token_secret = ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"]
end
```

then in your controller you can use TwitterClient everywhere to make your API calls.

Comment: But ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"] and ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET"] are differents for every user so I cannot store it somewhere "global" and I can know it before the log in ?! This is why I do the configuration only when they are logged in. Maybe I'm wrong ?!

Comment: The access token and access secret are different for every registered application ('user' of the Twitter API) not every individual user themselves. If you wish to integrate with Twitter's OAuth to provide a 'login with twitter' then I would consult Oauth for Twitter Developers. If you are looking to configure an automated client for multiple registered applications on the Twitter Rest Client, then you have a more complex task on your hand.